# reading from a txt file in c

Tags: c, file

so I am having trouble reading a text file and storing it into two arrays. I am very new to code, and feel like I'm missing some obvious things. I would like my code to be able to read the simple .txt file (shown below):

0.036 1.364
0.064 2.727
0.082 4.215
0.111 6.694
0.135 9.05
0.146 9.545
0.172 11.901
0.181 12.149
0.191 11.901
0.211 9.174
0.239 7.314
0.264 6.074
0.275 5.95
0.333 5.207
0.394 4.835
0.445 4.835
0.556 4.339
0.667 4.587
0.723 4.339
0.78 4.339
0.793 4.091
0.812 2.603
0.833 1.24
0.857 0.0

by storing the first column into one array and the next column into another array. Here is my current code:

```
int main(void)
{

    FILE *file = fopen("B6", "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file for reading.\n");
    }

    int array1[999], array2[999];

    int i = 0;

    while (fgetc(file) != EOF)
    {
        fscanf(file, "%d", &array1[i]);
        fscanf(file, "%d", &array2[i]);

        printf("%d\n", array1[i]);
        printf("%d\n", array2[i]);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(file);

}
```

The problem is, the program will automatically scanf to the next array if the number is a 0, decimal, space, or newline. I don't know how to specify for it not to do that, or to only skip some things, such as the newline. Here is an example of how it prints out:

0
0
36
1
364
0
64
2
727

If anyone has answers that would be great, thanks.

Comment: Looks like you have fractions, but you're trying to read into an integer with `%d`? I don't know how you expect it to work.

Comment: float array...; fscanf(file, "%f", &array1[i]); ??

Comment: `int array1[999], array2[999]` won't hold numbers that have a decimal point. Integers are whole numbers - they don't have fractional parts. Re-read your textbook or lessons on data types to find the difference between integer and floating point types. Reading the documentation for fscanf() and printf() format specifiers will help if you have trouble afterward.

Comment: ok, yup, I was dumb. It works now. I'm notin a class but trying to do this on my own, surviving off of the internet for help. thanks guys.